# How many contexts can be created on a Cisco ASA Active/Standby Pair?

Tags: cisco-asa

How many contexts can be created on a Cisco ASA Active/Standby pair with base license?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each physical firewall is licensed for two contexts with the base license. For example: an operational and an admin context. If you create an active/standby failover pair up to four contexts can be created as the licensing is shared between the physical devices. For Example: Operational 1, Operational 2, Operational 3, and an admin context.